# UIImageView aspect fit to height

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to set the UIImageView size aspectfit according to height .

means my requirement is that my height of image should be fix but the width of image should be change according to height i know that  in UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit it will take width and hieght automatically but what if i need fix height and dynamic width like aspectfit according to height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
double width = originalImage.size.width;
double height = originalImage.size.height;
double apect = width/height;

double nWidth = 320.f/ apect;
self.img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, nWidth, 320.f);
self.img.center = self.view.center;
self.img.image = originalImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGSize)resizeImage:(CGSize)imageSize toTargetedHeight:(float)height {

 NSLog(@"actualImageSize : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(imageSize));

 float scaleFactor = height / imageSize.height;
 float newHeight = imageSize.height * scaleFactor;
 float newWidth = imageSize.width  * scaleFactor;

 CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);

 NSLog(@"convertedImageSize : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));
 return newSize;

}
```

This will create your image with specific height with maintaining its aspect ratio.